# ¿Cómo puedo compilar en Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

¿Qué puedo hacer cuando siempre que quiero compilar un proyecto, para ver cómo corre, me aparece una ventana la cual dice que el programa se cerró inesperadamente?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en estos casos lo que me ha funcionado para estos casos es, siempre actualizar Xamarin a su última versión, instalar varios sdks de android y demás cosas, ademas verifica si tu instalación de visual studio no tenga algún archivo corrupto o algo por el estilo.